# VBA The item with specified name wasn't found

Tags: vba

I wanted to move a chart to a specified position. Here below are the VBA codes:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$B$22")
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "A vs B Chart"
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "A vs B Chart"
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 12).ParagraphFormat
    .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
    .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
End With
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 12).Font
    .BaselineOffset = 0
    .Bold = msoFalse
    .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
    .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
    .Fill.Transparency = 0
    .Fill.Solid
    .Size = 14
    .Italic = msoFalse
    .Kerning = 12
    .Name = "+mn-lt"
    .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
    .Spacing = 0
    .Strike = msoNoStrike
End With
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select

Dim oCell As Range
Set oCell = ActiveSheet.Range("P5")
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Left = oCell.Left ' this moves the chart left
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Top = oCell.Top 'move chart up
```

Run the above codes gives the run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)': The item with the specified name wasn't found. The debug points to the code:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Left = oCell.Left
```

How to address the error then?

Comment: It means the name isn't correct. If I were to guess, try "Chart1".

Comment: How to name the active chart with a specified name?

Answer (score 0):

First, assign the newly created chart to a variable . . .

```
Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers)
```

Then refer to your variable when assigning properties.  So, for example, to move the chart to the desired location . . .

```
With shp
    .Left = oCell.Left
    .Top = oCell.Top
End With
```

However, your code could be re-written as follows . . .

```
Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(Style:=240, XlChartType:=xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers, Left:=Range("P5").Left, Top:=Range("P5").Top)

With shp.Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$B$22")
    With .ChartTitle
        .Text = "A vs B Chart"
        With .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat
            .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
            .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
        End With
        With .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
            .BaselineOffset = 0
            .Bold = msoFalse
            .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
            .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
            .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
            .Fill.Transparency = 0
            .Fill.Solid
            .Size = 14
            .Italic = msoFalse
            .Kerning = 12
            .Name = "+mn-lt"
            .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
            .Spacing = 0
            .Strike = msoNoStrike
        End With
    End With
End With
```